# User Database Permissions - Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, windows-authentication

Is it possible to pass Windows domain credentials (users) from their browser directly to MSSQL for database authentication?

Still learning ASP.NET and EF, but I have a working webapp that uses a static DB connection string in my webconfig.  I'm using Windows Authentication via IIS to control access to the website, but I need to support read/write permissions in the database, per user.

It would be great if I could just use AD and assign permissions directly in SQL server, instead of having to maintain my own user table and permissions/roles.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with impersonation. You can configure it to pass the same credentials from the IIS to SQL Server, however, if SQL server is physically in another server, you might need to give some permissions to users. I have done this years ago, but couldn't do it again recently.